# Ngxs - Proper way of consuming api?

Tags: angular, rxjs, state, ngxs

I want to have 3 actions for an api call. GetItem, GetItemFailed, GetItemSuccess.

I'm not much familiar with rxjs operators so I only use subscribe for api calls.

Something like this:

```
@Action(GetItem)
getItem(sc: StateContext<ItemStateModel>, { payload }: GetItem) {
  sc.patchState({
    isLoading: true
  });

  this.itemService.getItem(payload)
    .subscribe(item => {
      sc.dispatch(new GetItemSuccess(item));
    }, error => {
      sc.dispatch(new GetItemFailed(error));
    });
}
```

I did a little bit of googling ngxs examples and found out most people use pipe with tap/take/first so I refactor the subscribe in my action to something like this:

```
  return this.itemService.getItem(payload).pipe(
    tap(({ item }) => {
       return sc.dispatch(new GetItemSuccess(item));
    }),
    catchError(({ error }) => {
      return sc.dispatch(new GetItemFailed(error));
    })
  );
```

It worked, but when I check the redux dev tools, **the GetItemSucess is fired first before GetItem.**

Can anyone show me the proper way on calling api on action with success/fail. Can't seem to find a good example online.

Comment: GetItem is not in your example so where should it come from?

Comment: It's there though?

Answer (score 0):

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/139) in NGXS relating to the ordering of actions in the Redux dev tools - suspect this is what you are seeing.

Comment: Oh, that sucks. I thought I'm doing something wrong.